# How to check empty value in an attribute in the cloudant selector query when there is an entry of design document is present in cloudant database

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, cloudant

[image: error]In this scenario, I am using a design document in my document, by creating an index query, but when I run the below selector query in Cloudant, it gives this error:

```
{
      "selector": {
        "ne_status": {
            "$eq": "Q"
        },
        "type": {
            "$eq": "weak"
        },
        "parentId": {
            "$eq": ""
        }
    }
    }
```

After some digging, I found the issue; it is with this statement:

```
**"parentId": {
        "$eq": ""
    }**
```

In my scenario I have to check

```
"parentId" = ""
```

If I remove this statement, then the selector query works fine.

There might be another way to execute the query with the highlighted text, but in that scenario we have to remove design document, which will not be the correct scenario as per our program, 
because we are executing the selector through the java program.

Is there some other way to check the empty values in the selector query?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select documents that don't include the `parentId` property using the [`$exists` selector](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#creating-selector-expressions):

```
  "selector": {
       ...
       ,
       "parentId": {
          "$exists": false
        }
  }
```

Setting `"$exists": true` returns documents that contain the property.

You could also use the following expression

```
{
  "selector": {
    "ne_status": {
         "$eq": "Q"
     },
     "type": {
         "$eq": "weak"
     },
     "parentId": {
         "$eq": ""
     }
 },
 "fields": [
   "_id",
   "_rev"
 ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, later option fails(attached screenshot), former one runs but giving false results.
for eg: what if "parentId" = "1", I want to exclude these records too, but it include that record also.
i want to get only those records whose "parentId" = ""

Comment: The query (I updated sample 2 above to describe the entire query) is returning the expected results in my environment. Can you open the Cloudant Query editor in full screen mode (click on the two opposing arrows), copy and paste my complete example and run the query? If the same error is returned, can yo please take a screen capture of the editor in full-screen mode so the entire query is visible? Thanks!

Comment: Let me tell you something this query is working fine because you directly executed, which is absolutely fine.

Comment: but if you try to execute with design document it will give error.
I have tried and i got the error(attaching screenshot).
If i don't create the design document query is working fine, but after creating it the issue is coming, and the issue is specifically because of checking null or empty i.e. **"parentid" = ""**.

Comment: If you want to check the scenario please create the design document 
steps: Go to design document in Databases and then in design document, then in query indexes.
after clicking in query indexes please paste this set of code 
**{ "index": {}, "type": "text" }** in index area and click on create index.
after clicking on create index, you will see  a new record named _design document_ will be created in your database.
after that if you try the same query you will get the error.

Comment: Also design document is necessary in my case because i am creating the selector through java program and it needs design document for indexing and other related issues.

Comment: With the additional information you've provided I was able to re-create your problem  scenario. Apparently the text index can't directly handle a search for an empty value. My suggestion is to change your document structure to not include the 'parentId' property if its value is the empty string if your application logic doesn't need to distinguish between a null and an empty value. With that change you can use '"$exists": false' as a condition to identify documents that don't have a parent id.

Comment: Thanks, will try to workaround.
But just wondering how IBM clodant team left this, if it is purposely done whats the reason behind that.

Comment: Cloudant/CouchDb's search is based on [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/). It is my understanding that Lucene doesn't really support searches for the empty value, therefore some kind of workaround needs to be used to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.